# What is a Majorana spinor-vector gravitino?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, majorana-fermions

I started to read about superstring theory, I do not have a good basis on SUGRA but I got asked to directly jump into superstrings.

Following ``Basic concepts of String Theory'' (Springer), I have two questions related to subsection 7.2 (Superstrings action and its symmetries) about the gravitino and spinor fields.

1. The book states:

> The gravitino is a world-sheet vector and a world-sheet Majorana spinor

it also calls the gravitino **Majorana spinor-vector**. What does exactly mean to be simultaneously a worldsheet spinor and a worldsheet vector? Shouldn't it be a ST spinor and a WS vector?

2. While writing the action, to have local SUSY, we add plus the existing d bosons, d fermions + d auxiliar real scalar fields. Why do we have to add those extra scalar fields?